# React app on GitHub Pages - URL missing repository name

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am keeping images in a folder `public/assets/img`. Then I use it in a component like that:

`const imageUrl = "/assets/img/image.png"`

Locally everything works fine, but on GitHub Pages in an image URL somehow name of my repo is missing, so instead of

`http://name.github.io/my-repo/assets/img/image.png` I get `http://name.github.io/assets/img/image.png`

I was following an instruction on how to create a GitHub Pages build and added in package.json the URL of my project, namely `"homepage": "https://name.github.io/my-repo"`

-- edit --

Also, I've just now realized, that although the routing seems to work fine, it also misses my repository name in the URL, so instead of

`http://name.github.io/my-repo/subpage` there is

`http://name.github.io/subpage`

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you please try with `assets/img/image.png`

Comment: doesn't work then locally

Comment: Should work in git, when you use `/assets/...`  actually it resolves to the root, since you are inside the sub root which is `https://root/subroot` you need to remove `/`

Comment: Do you use the normal webpack setup? Did you use create react app?

Comment: adding slash in front of assets makes the image crash locally. I've tried now adding slash at the end of my `homepage` path but it didn't change anything.
I've used create react app.

Comment: now I've realized that although my routing works fine it also misses my repo name in the URL... so its `http://name.github.io/subage`. I've edited my post

Comment: You likely need to specify `/my-repo` in <base> and use `assets/img/image.png` relative path instead of absolute.

Comment: thank you very much, I had a white screen when opening the local server, I couldn't understand why, it turns out the problem was in the package.json: wrong url in homepage, it was like this "https://github.com/DaLVeRS2001/DaLVeRS2001#readme" , and it was necessary so "https://github.com/DaLVeRS2001". I am from Russia. recently I started to study all this.

Comment: Does someone have an updated good answer for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I somehow have solved my problems, however, I am not quite satisfied with the solutions:

**Fixing the URL problem** (missing repo name in the URL)

I've added a `basename` property to my router `<BrowserRouter basename="/repo-name">`

Downsides: Firstly, it doesn't look good hardcoded. Secondly, `npm start` opens `localhost:3000` which is empty now. I have to add my repo name to open the app locally, so `localhost:3000/repo-name` - not too neat.

**Fixing images problem** (also missing repo name in the URL and thus not displaying images)

I've added a `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` variable to the image URL: `const imageUrl = ${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/image.png`. In local environment it's empty, deployed it takes `homepage` value from `package.json`, which is `https://name.github.io/repo-name`

Downside: one has to add `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` before every image displayed in a component.

I would be grateful for any better solution!